How to build the branch that was just pushed
I have a repository on GitHub with multiple branches, and I want to automate my builds.
I have the logic to build my branch using the Git List Branch plugin.
1
My problem is that I want to automatically build the branch that was just pushed. I just need to know the name of the branch, but that's where I'm stuck—I don't know what type of project I need or what the next step should be.
This is my jenkins file that im using to run a branch but my problem is how to automate the build of the branch that was just pushed
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'main', url: '------------'
            }
        }
        stage('Get Branches') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def branches = bat(script: 'git ls-remote --heads ----------------', returnStdout: true).trim()
                    def branchList = branches.split('\n').collect { it.split('/').last() }
                    branchList = branchList.drop(1)
                    echo "Branches found: ${branchList.join(', ')}"
                    branchList.each { branch ->
                        echo "Processing branch: ${branch}"
                        bat """
                            docker-compose build --build-arg BRANCH_NAME=${branch}
                            docker-compose up -d
                            docker exec -t tinyp-ci /bin/bash -c "run-tests.sh"
                            docker exec -t tinyp-ci /bin/bash -c "cd -------------------"
                            docker-compose down
                        """
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


What you're looking for is a multi-branch pipeline. This scans your repo for all the branches you have in it. Once the scan is complete you can have the pipeline automatically build any new branches it detects. It will also build any new changes that are pushed into the branch. A full tutorial can be found in the official docs.
You don't need to create a parameterized project where the branch needs to be selected. The multi-branch pipelines handles all that. You can re-use the Jenkinsfile you have shown above.

Set up a multibranch job that triggers pipeline at each branch push (there are plenty of tutorials that explain how).
Your pipeline will become as simple as this :
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                checkout scm
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def branchName = env.BRANCH_NAME
                    echo "Building branch: ${branchName}"
                    bat """
                        docker-compose build --build-arg BRANCH_NAME=${branchName}
                        docker-compose up -d
                        docker exec -t tinyp-ci /bin/bash -c "run-tests.sh"
                        docker exec -t tinyp-ci /bin/bash -c "cd /path/to/your/project"
                        docker-compose down
                    """
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

